# 8 team schedule with 6 different events

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for a schedule for an eight team tournament with 6 different event stations where the teams can only play a station once and have to play a different team each of the 6 rounds.  So teams will end up playing a different team all 6 stations.  Only 4 of the stations will end up being played each round 2 stations will not be played each round. Example of start of schedule:

```
         Round 1    Rd 2    Rd 3   Rd 4    Rd 5    Rd 6
```

Blackjack    1 vs 2;    No game

Pictionary   3 vs 4;    1 vs 7

Connect Four 5 vs 6;    2 vs 4

Trivia       7 vs 8;    3 vs 6

Twister      No game;   5 vs 8

Charades     No game;   No game

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally solve this by writing a program to do so.

My program would first use symmetries to say that after reordering events, rounds and teams you can  schedule team 1 to play teams 2..7 on rounds 1..6, for events 1..5, team 8 will play one round later against somebody else.  On round 1, team 8 plays team 3 on event 6.

I would then do a brute force search.

To speed up the search, you want to find conflicts as quickly as possible.  That can be arranged by always first looking at the most constrained options that you can at every point.  This will add constraints to those quickly, and therefore increase your odds of finding conflicts.

In this case I would each time pick the time slot which has been most played (hoping to fill time slots quickly), then order available events from most played to least played (hoping to find time conflicts between players who need to play that event together), then within each event+time slot order teams from most scheduled to least, then order their potential opponents who have not yet been considered from most scheduled to least.  I would then try options recursively in that order, backing up to higher decisions after all paths lead to conflict.

If there is a solution it should be filled in fairly quickly.  If there is no solution..well..it is a large search space but it should still be searchable in acceptable time.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help!  However, I don't understand what a brute force search is or how to write a program for it.